# Does scala/java has something like StringIO from python?

Tags: java, scala

I would like to know that if java/scala has the "string object that could act as file" as StringIO in python ? I figure that it would be better than writing and reading alot of temporary file. I prefer scala but java one should be fine too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how this is being used. You see, while you *do* stuff with a file in Python, *you don't do anything with a `File` in Java*! Well, aside from tasks like checking permission, creating, etc.

All I/O in Java *and Scala* is based on one of two concepts:

- `InputStream` and `OutputStream`
- `Reader` and `Writer`

What you do is *create* one of these classes passing a `File` as *parameter*. So, if whatever API you are using is intent on receiving a `File`, you can't do anything about it. However, APIs will usually take one of the above classes, not a `File`, and all of them have a string-version available.

As for Scala, there's also `scala.io.Stream`, for which you can also create one based on a `String`.

Comment: My intent is that since the data is generate in java/scala, I just don't want to write it on my disk before passing it to another function that require file (which, I don't have a source of.). But I will keep that in mind when writing my own code. Thanks for clear explanation.

Answer (score 12):

I believe [`StringWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I am not sure if that is what I'm looking for. I want to know if there is a class that I could manipulate like string but also could use as a argument for function that want File as parameter.

Comment: @Tg: No, in that case there is nothing you can do, because File is basically a wrapper around a path, it does not itself have any methods to access content.

Comment: Ok then. I would like to use StringIO since I used it heavily in python. I guess I have to write it down first.

Answer (score 3):

Java has the [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).

```
OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
out.write(...);
String result = new String(out.toByteArray());
```